# Flutter table_calendar Calendar Style

Tags: flutter, user-interface, calendar, user-experience, table-calendar

I am using the table_calendar Flutter package. I was wondering if it would be possible to style the calendar similar to googles (and most) calendar(s). I want it to display the appointments directly unter the date and not displayed as dots.
I cant find anything online.
My background is not coding but I am happy to learn (I know a little Flutter).

I want ist like this

[image]

but table_calendar looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Good calendars are surprinsingly difficult to find. `table_calendar` is already the best find nowadays.

From what I know, there's no free package which offers that kind of experience.
A calendar like Google's would require either a payed calendar, like sync_fusion, or to create your own calendar package.

You can try using builder methods in the package to try and achieve something closer, but I think you'd quickly be stuck in some features, so I actually recommend trying to create your own calendar.

Packages are open source by default, so you can check on how table_calendar is implemented if you need an idea on how to make it work.

I started a package myself like that, but we decided to keep table_calendar experience until a real need about improvement appeared.

My advice is, if this is a product, try to work with the current package so you can at least release the app and start getting useful feedbacks about experience. With the app already running and possibly getting some revenue, you can focus on creating the calendar package.

Comment: thank you @LucasNantes for the precise answer. An own calendar? that wont happen I am afraid. Coding is new to me and my background is nursing. cheers